# Searching XML through Java Codes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have around 30 xml files with proper formatting  and huge amount of data. I want to search these xml files for specific data retrival. Can you suggest any site or blog which i can use as aguideline to solve my problem.

I need to search inside of each tag for the keyword provided by the user. And also sometime the specific tag name which will return the content inside the tag according to the user request.

example : a.xml, b.xml, c.xml

```
inside a.xml 

<abc>
some content 
</abc>
```

User may search for abc the tag or some keyword inside the content. In both cases it should return the content or if more than one match then it should return the link for both by clicking which the user can see them one by one.

Comment: If you have XSD files for these xml-s - you may use JAXB. For code generation use xjc tool from java/bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using XPath, which is a SQL-like language for searching in XML documents

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html

Comment: Thanks Xpath was easy and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use a SAX parser (no need to go back and forth within the documents plus huge amount of data hence don't use a DOM parser).

See [this link](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=saxparser1.sql&id=18232) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You may store your XMLs into an XML database (for example [eXist](http://www.exist-db.org/)), and then query it using [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).

Comment: if i am using it in a application then it wont be a effective method i guess. cause the users wont be having the database support.

Comment: There are two aspects here: (1) how do user input a query in your application? (2) how does your application perform that query and return result to user? My answer was targeting aspect (2): you may have your XML stored in an XML database, and then use the java API of the XML database to query it sing XQuery, get the result back, and display to the user (eXist has also RESTful APIs). Aspect (1) is a totally different thing: it's a problem of user interaction, and of how to make it easy for your user to specify a query.